# Is there any way to use polymorphic relation, without the namespace FQDN

Tags: php, laravel

I have a **polymorphic** relationship and in my database i have one field called entity_type where the namespaces are saved ( models namespace for the polymorphic relationship )
like that normally : `App\Models\MyModelName;`

Is there any way to use polymorphic relationship without the full FQDN, I would like to save only `MyModelName` instead of `App\Models\MyModelsName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map these models to what ever you would like to so you could shorten their names to what ever you like. There is a method named `morphMap` and `enforceMorphMap` (which calls `morphMap`) on `Relation` that allows you to map these classes to a shorter name:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::enforceMorphMap([
    'post' => 'App\Models\Post',
    ...
]);
```

You can add that code to the `boot` method of a Service Provider

[Laravel 9.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Custom Polymophic Types](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types) `enforceMorphMap`

Answer (score -1):

you can't save on the model names in polymorphic relationship...

Laravel stores the model name with its namespace in other to avoid conflicts with Models which might have thesame name